# What DLC has the most contracts on the bounty board?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide

I need to know because I need the most key contracts out of a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contracts are tied to maps. You can get a total of 6 contracts a day, and they appear to be randomly selected from the total amount of maps available (not just the ones you own). I believe 3 are always from the base game, but I'm not 100% sure, so the other 3 will come from DLC. The DLC add the following maps:

- [Schluesselschloss](https://store.steampowered.com/app/437070/Warhammer_End_Times__Vermintide_Schluesselschloss/) adds only a single map, The Last Stand
- [Karak Azgaraz](https://store.steampowered.com/app/463791/Warhammer_End_Times__Vermintide_Karak_Azgaraz/) adds three new maps: Khazid Kro, The Cursed Rune and Chain of Fire
- [Drachenfels](https://store.steampowered.com/app/453280/Warhammer_End_Times__Vermintide_Drachenfels/) also adds three new maps: Summoner's Peak, Castle Drachenfels and The Dungeons
- [Stromdorf](https://store.steampowered.com/app/463795/Warhammer_End_Times__Vermintide_Stromdorf/) adds only two new maps: The Courier and Reaching Out
- [Death of the Reik](https://store.steampowered.com/app/741420/Warhammer_End_Times__Vermintide_Death_on_the_Reik/) also adds only two new maps: Reikwald Forest and The River Reik

Therefore, Karaz Azgaraz and Drachenfels would be the best DLC to get, to give you the most new quests; however, they are more expensive than the ones that give two maps, so that may be something to consider.